# scp stopped working in the middle of a large file transfer to SSH server with Nautilus

Tags: ssh, fedora, scp

I have a Fedora 35 home server set up. I use sshd with the default settings. Up until today, I could ssh and scp without any issues and had no problems with this machine.

This morning, from my two other Fedora computers, I tried to mount the server using `ssh://<server-ip>` in Nautilus to back up some files. This succeeded, and Nautilus was showing progress transferring the files. Halfway through, something happened to the connection and Nautilus showed an error message.

After that, I can no longer mount the server with `ssh://<server-ip>` in Nautilus. I also can't run a command with ssh unless I use the -t option.

Examples:

```
$ ssh <server-ip>
works fine
$ ssh <server-ip> echo hello
Timeout, server not responding
$ ssh <server-ip> -t 'echo hello'
hello
Conection to <server-ip> closed
$ scp test.txt <server-ip>:~/
Timeout, server not responding
```

What could have happened on the server side that's causing this behavior? Some sort of rate limit, firewall, etc.? I tried restarting sshd on the server side which didn't change.

I have seen some tips that say that a printed message from ssh/bash_profile could be causing issues, but I have no such message.

Comment: Reboot, try again, post on a site where it is on topic when it occurs again. Voting to close the question.

Comment: I'll post to ServerFault, but rebooting is a weak suggestion when debugging is possible while the system is up and can still be investigated.

Comment: If this only happens once it's not worth the time it takes to investigate.

Comment: Fair enough. I flagged it for moderator intervention to move it to SuperUser for now.